# Flutter how to change value of a class object

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I try to work with class but I don't see how to apply a new value to a parameter of my User object in a foreach loop because the parameter is a variable.

**My class User :**

```
class UsersList{
  List<User> users;

  UsersList({
    this.users
  });

  factory UsersList.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<User> users= List<User>();

    users= json.map((i) => User.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return UsersList(
      users : users
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "users": users,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{'
        'users: ${this.users},'
        '}';
  }
}

class User{
  int type;
  String name;
  bool gender;
  num distance;
  num index;
  num position;
  num fuel;
  num values

  User({
    this.type,
    this.name,
    this.gender,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return User(
      type : json['type'],
      name: json['name'],
      gender : json['gender'],
      distance: json['distance'],
      index: json['index'],
      position: json['position'],
      fuel: json['fuel'],
      values: json['values'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "type" : type,
    "name" : name,
    "gender" : gender,
    "distance" : distance,
    "index" : index,
    "position" : position,
    "fuel" : fuel,
    "values" : values,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{'
        'type : ${this.type},'
        'name: ${this.name},'
        'gender : ${this.gender},'
        'distance: ${this.distance},'
        'index: ${this.index},'
        'position: ${this.position},'
        'fuel: ${this.fuel},'
        'values: ${this.values},'
        '}';
  }
 }
```

**And this is my function :**

```
static User rebuildUser(User item, UsersList usersJson, FormCalculator formData)
  {
    if(usersJson== null || usersJson.users.isEmpty) return null;

    final User _rebuild = User();
    List<User> _allUsersType = usersJson.users.where((c) => (c.type == item.type)).toList();
    User_upperItem = _allUsersType.firstWhere((c) => (c.distance > item.distance));

    item.toJson().forEach((key, value) {
      if (key != "type" && key != 'distance' && key != 'index')
      {
        final _newValue = CalculatorInitial.calculateNew(item, _upperItem, formData.distance, "distance", key);
        _rebuild.toJson()[key] = _newValue; // ----- This not work ! -----
      }
    });

    return _rebuild; // The values ​​of my User rebuild are unchanged because all of which are null

  }
```

This function allows me to reconstruct a user with data calculated between 2 users.
This function works because I get the desired result. I don't see **how to apply these new values ​​in my user object**. I use the "toJson ()" function to be able to have the key as a variable but it doesn't seem to apply the new values ​​to my object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```dart
item.toJson().forEach((key, value) {
      if (key != "type" && key != 'distance' && key != 'index')
      {
        final _newValue = CalculatorInitial.calculateNew(item, _upperItem, formData.distance, "distance", key);
        myMap.add(key: key, value:vale);
      }
    });
    
    _rebuild = User(myMap);
```